# Using two different chargers for the same laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, voltage, charger

I have laptop HP 650 G1
It came with charger with specs:

```
INPUT 240V - 1.6A 50-60 HZ
OUTPUT 19.5 V-3.33 A
```

So I want to know is it safe to charge laptop with another charger (same connector, also from HP) with different specs.:

```
INPUT 140-240V - 1.5 A 50-60 HZ
OUTPUT 19V -4.74A
```

I meant charging and using while on charger.

Comment: The other charger is capable of delivering more current than the laptop needs, but the voltage is the same, so it will not force more current than the laptop requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll be fine. The output voltage is well within tolerance range and it does not matter that the second charger *can* provide more current (4.74 amps vs 3.33). It only matters that it can provide at least as much as the previous.

(Similarly: The power outlets where you live can probably provide 15 or 20 amps, but it's perfectly safe to plug in a tiny night-light that uses only a fraction of an amp. A car battery can provide hundreds of amps - for a short time - and this is needed when you start the car, but it's perfectly fine to connect a tiny bulb across it that uses less than an amp. And so on.)